# Stop browser recording history for a particular website

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, plugins, history

Is there any way I can prevent the browser to record the history for a particular website with the help of a plugin(as I can't find any)? As I don't think there's any inbuilt feature for doing this *except the Icognito Mode*?

As using icognito, it doesn't preserve history for any website, but I want something where I can have an exclude list of websites to be excluded by browser to save history for.

Comment: Why not have 2 browsers running? One running Private / Incognito for your 'hidden' need, and the other browser running normally?

Answer (score 3):

If its chrome, then the extension [History site blocker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/history-site-blocker/bkgnheiibhnjklgimaldgngjcfblachh) might help you. From the google chrome extension page:

> History site blocker is an extension for Chrome that disables the
>   record of some sites in Chrome history. You can edit the list of
>   domains to not record in history, separating them by ",".

Comment: The extension does not exist anymore.

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/history-blocker-by-site/keamekimefemnbgegbfkdkmbomaahfai/related

Answer (score 1):

Possible answer (Credit: Lifehacker.Com): [Incognito-Filter for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/incognito-filter/cifilbmpnkjinlkchohdfcpdkmpngiik)

Description from the addon:

```
Open specific websites in a sandboxed Incognito Window, permanently.
```

Comment: The extension does not exist anymore.